# HTML table column group with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-table

I am fetching multiple table data from database with Ajax and PHP in array result1 and result2, And i am trying to display result2 data in table in which i want the first tr of the table as group column.

I am trying with the following script but its giving this result.[image: this]

And this is is the desired result.

[image]

**JS Script**

```
function getResult(id = null) {
if(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {      

            $("#Id").html(response.result1.id);
            $("#client").html(response.result1.client);
            $("#reg_Date").html(response.result1.reg_Date);
            $("#due_date").html(response.result1.due_date);

            response.result2.forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(element);
            var category = element.category;
            var names= element.name;
            var Result = element.result;

                $('table tr').length;
                html = '<tr>';
                html += '<td><p>'+category+'</p></td>';
                 html += '</tr>';
                $('table').append(html);

                $('table tr').length;
                html = '<tr>';
                html += '<td><p>'+names+'</p></td>';
                html += '<td><p>'+Result+'</p></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
                $('table').append(html);
        });
    }
   });
  } else {
        alert('error');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check to see if the category name is different, and skip outputting another category if it's the same:

```
// Store the last category output here
var lastCategory = null;
response.result2.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
    var category = element.category;
    var names= element.name;
    var Result = element.result;

    // Is the category different? Output it
    if (lastCategory != category) {
        $('table tr').length;
        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><p>'+category+'</p></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        $('table').append(html);
        // Update the last category
        lastCategory = category;
    }

    ...
```